# Is the doctype declaration HTML or SGML?

Tags: html, doctype, sgml

Doctype declaration is not a HTML tag nor element, but is it HTML code? Some of my peers told me it is HTML still because it is part of a HTML document, but others told me it is instead something called SGML. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93296/relation-and-differences-between-sgml-xml-html-and-xhtml

Comment: Your question is most probably an opinion, rather than something that can be definitively answered.

Comment: Based on the link you shared it seems like the doctype declaration would be both?

Comment: "Both" is probably the best way to think of it, yes. The doctype has its origins in SGML, but its use in modern HTML has become divorced from those origins.